# Ruby Sequel MatchData Error "can't express #<MatchData"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have one variable with number and text concatenated (e.g. "[79511]Rocket"). If this variable does contains numbers inside the brackets, I must store then (numbers only) in one column of my table. I'm validating this with the below code:

```
enterprise_id = "[79511]Rocket".split(/[\[\]]/x)[1].match(/^(\d)+$/) rescue nil
```

When I test in with Puts, it works as 79511, fine.
But then when I run the code to insert into database like below:

```
enterprise_id = "[79511]Rocket".split(/[\[\]]/x)[1].match(/^(\d)+$/) rescue nil
insert_ds = DB["INSERT INTO pd_deals ( enterprise_id ) VALUES (?)",  enterprise_id]
insert_ds.insert
```

The target column is Integer type in table.

It throws an error:

```
/home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1252:in `literal_other_append': can't express #<MatchData "79511" 1:"1"> as a SQL literal (Sequel::Error)
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:108:in `literal_append'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:673:in `block in placeholder_literal_string_sql_append'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:670:in `loop'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:670:in `placeholder_literal_string_sql_append'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/sql.rb:109:in `to_s_append'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1214:in `literal_expression_append'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:86:in `literal_append'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:345:in `literal'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:1534:in `static_sql'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/sql.rb:23:in `insert_sql'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:334:in `insert'
    from /home/bm93/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sequel-4.34.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/postgres.rb:1355:in `insert'
    from tt.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I'm doing this way because I need to extract a number from a string. Any hint there? Is there any way better?

Comment: You can get the string representation of the number like so: "`[79511]Rocket"[/\[(\d+)\]/, 1] #=> "79511"`. Tack on `.to_i` if you want the integer `79511`. A variant is `"[79511]Rocket"[/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/] #=> "79511"`, where `(?<=\[)` is a ("zero-width") *positive lookbehind* that matches a left bracket and `(?=\])` is a *positive lookahead* that matches a right bracket.

Comment: @CarySwoveland So I used "[79511]Rocket"[/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/]. Worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute:

```
"[79511]Rocket".split(/[\[\]]/x)[1].match(/^(\d)+$/)
```

in `irb`, you'll see:

```
=> #<MatchData "79511" 1:"1">
```

because [`String#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match) returns a `MatchData` instance and calling `inspect` on a `MatchData` gives you `#<MatchData ...>`. If you `puts` that value:

```
puts "[79511]Rocket".split(/[\[\]]/x)[1].match(/^(\d)+$/)
```

you'll see `79511` because `puts` calls `to_s` on its arguments to convert them to strings.

Sequel won't call `to_s`, it will try to figure out how to translate the argument to something the database understands on its own and it doesn't know what to do with a `MatchData` instance, hence the:

```
can't express #<MatchData "79511" 1:"1"> as a SQL literal
```

error.

You could call `to_s` yourself:

```
DB["INSERT INTO pd_deals ( enterprise_id ) VALUES (?)",  enterprise_id.to_s.presence]
```

or use the `MatchData#[]` method:

```
DB["...", enterprise_id ? enterise_id[0] : nil]
```

or even use `String#[]` as Cary Swoveland suggests:

```
enterprise_id = "[79511]Rocket"[/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/]
DB["...", enterprise_id.presence]
```

I'm not that familiar with Sequel so you might need some `to_i` calls in there to convert the `'79511'` strings to `79511` numbers.

Comment: I endup using "[79511]Rocket"[/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/] with no need to add any method on insert statement. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Cool, that's a nice clean approach. You could also do it with [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-scan) but that's more appropriate when you're looking for multiple things.